# slicer ordered in power BI

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I have a report in power bi that shows me the company result, I created a calculated column that give me the fiscal year. I inserted a slicer so I can select the fiscal year I want to see.

Now the slicer is ordered ascending, from 2001 to 2018, I would like to have it ordered in a different way, from 2018 to 2001.

I can't find the way to do it. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to sort or reverse sort using the ellipsis (...) in the upper right corner as seen here:

[image: Date Sort]